# Why did my code result in a null pointer exception?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I realize that similar questions have been asked before but I'm a beginner programmer working on my first app and would greatly appreciate if someone could help me understand using my specific code.

Today's the first time this appeared. I published my game a few weeks ago and dozens of people have played it with no issues so I'm trying to figure out why this happened now when the same code worked successfully probably at least 50 times before.

It happened 10 seconds after session start:

Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

The two lines of code involved appear in the onTick method of a CountDownTimer that's started when the user clicks a button. They are:

```
View currentView = gridView.getChildAt(randomPosition);
ImageView image = (ImageView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

The GridView is implemented near the beginning of the onCreate method:

```
  adapter = new ButtonAdapter(this, clickButtons);
  gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
  gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I'm guessing that the gridView was somehow null but since the code that implements it in onCreate runs before the CountDownTimer is started, I'm not sure how that's possible.

Edit: now I'm beginning to think the problem is in the adapter.

```
public class ButtonAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ClickButton> {


public ButtonAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull ClickButton[] objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View gridItemView = convertView;
    if (gridItemView == null) {
        gridItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.button, parent, false);
    }

    ClickButton currentButton = getItem(position);

    ImageView button = (ImageView) gridItemView.findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setImageResource(currentButton.mSource);
    button.setAlpha(currentButton.mOpacity);

    return gridItemView;
}
}
```

Android Studio wants me to replace

```
button.setImageResource(currentButton.mSource);
button.setAlpha(currentButton.mOpacity);
```

with

```
button.setImageResource(currentButton != null ? currentButton.mSource : 
0);
button.setAlpha(currentButton != null ? currentButton.mOpacity : 
0);
```

Can someone explain what these changes do? Do you think that not having these changes is what caused the crash and do you have any idea why the crash only occurred once and not every time you use the app?

Comment: [`getChildAt` returns null](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt(int)) when no child is at the position. How do you pick `randomPosition` ?

Comment: I use `randomPosition = random.nextInt(arraySize);` I don't think that's the issue, could the adapter itself be the problem?

Comment: And are you sure the the array you passed to the adapter have exactly `arraySize` elements in it? Could you post the code that initalise the adapter and `arraySize`?

Comment: Android studio wants you do to these change because there could be a theoritical risk that `currentButton` is null. But looking at the exception message you've given. It has nothing to do with your current problem.

Comment: arraySize is a constant `private final int arraySize = 88;` and its value never changes.  Adapter is initialized with  `adapter = new ButtonAdapter(this, clickButtons);` clickbuttons is initialized with `private final ClickButton[] clickButtons = new ClickButton[arraySize];` and with  `for (int i = 0; i < clickButtons.length; i++) {
            clickButtons[i] = new ClickButton();
            clickButtons[i].mOpacity = 1.0f;
        }`